# How to enhance query to make it run fast and less time?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

I work on SQL server 2012 query I face issue : when run query return 10 rows for only one part

it take 50 second I try to run it in another time may be PC have more load

but it take same time 50 second to return 10 rows for only one part .

50 second for 10 rows it is more

I have  10000 part and records related  15 million so I need to enhance performance to be best

so what I do to make query run in small time

this is my query :

see execution plan below :

```
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyclwfSev
```

I try to solve issue by doing :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index1 
ON [dbo].[Excel_DK] ([PartNumber]) INCLUDE ([ZPartId],[FeatureName],[Value])
```

but it take 25 second to return 10 rows it still more

are there are any thing can do to enhance performance

Comment: I think a good start is to right click on the query and choose: "Analyze Query in database engine tuning advisor" in the context menu. And also, the question is missing the actual query, so you need to include that in the question

Comment: Is the execution plan you posted at PasteThePlan from before or after you added the nonclustered index `[index1]`? If it's after, you might want to try temporarily adding a RECOMPILE option to the end of your query and executing again. And you might want to add a clustered index to `#getDeliveryConfiguration` table with a key column of `DK_Feature`.

Comment: Also, row estimates can be way off if you're using declared variables: [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84626/estimated-rows-very-wrong-when-using-declared-variables]. Try bundling this up as a stored proc, even a temp one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your execution plan it seems that the data in your temporary table is a about `~ 400 000` rows. Lately, because of filtering (using `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` clause) the data flow is reduced to `10` rows.

The temporary table itself, seems to be quite big - the `Estimate data size` is `1 MB`, but the actual is `28 MB`.

The above can be easily seen on the next screenshot (check the rows after each block):

[image]

So, what you can do is to create smaller version your temporary table and apply the filtering in advance. For example:

```
SELECT FM.Z_FeatureID, FM.StatusId,FM.SplitFlag,FM.DkFeatureId,FM.separator,FM.separatororder
INTO #TEMP
from #getDeliveryConfiguration FM with(nolock)  
join [Excel_DK].dbo.Excel_DK DUFP with(nolock) on DUFP.FeatureName =FM.DK_Feature 
join [Z2DataCompanyManagement].[CompanyManagers].[Company] C with(nolock) on p.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
where C.CompanyName=@companyName And DUFP.PartNumber=@partNumber
```

and then replace the `#TEMP` in your original query. Of course, you can try another filtering, but the idea is to limit the rows in advance and than to read the data from the other tables.